# Make complex table layout using Vue components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vue-component, element

Hi I am trying to make this layout
[image: layout I want to achieve]
using component:
[element.eleme.io/table](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table) and Vue Js
I am facing an issue in making this section.

The table summary section:
 [image: the table summary section]
using table component 
this is the code

```
<el-table
          ref="multipleTable"
          :data="tableData3"
          :stripe="true"
          border
          style="width: 100%"
          @selection-change="handleSelectionChange"
        >
          <el-table-column type="selection" width="55"/>
          <el-table-column label="S.No." width="120" type="index"/>
          <el-table-column property="name" label="Part Name" width="120"/>
          <el-table-column property="part_labour" label="Part/Labour" show-overflow-tooltip/>
          <el-table-column property="part_number" label="Part Number" show-overflow-tooltip/>
          <el-table-column property="package_name" label="Package Name" show-overflow-tooltip/>
          <el-table-column property="price" label="Qty./Price(INR)" show-overflow-tooltip/>
          <el-table-column property="hsn" label="HSN" show-overflow-tooltip/>
          <el-table-column property="discount" label="Discount" show-overflow-tooltip/>
          <el-table-column property="tax_percentage" label="Tax%" show-overflow-tooltip/>
          <el-table-column property="tax" label="Tax" show-overflow-tooltip/>
          <el-table-column property="total" label="Total" show-overflow-tooltip/>
        </el-table>
```

I want to create the Grand Total Discount section with in this table

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please specify what the specific issue is that you are encountering and ideally show code for what you have tried. Otherwise this question is likely to get closed for being unclear or off topic.

Comment: I have shared the code please have a view

Comment: Hopefully someone with element experience will be able to chime in but you'll need to show the vue data source as well to get much help.

Comment: By " show the vue data source " do you mean the data I am sending to this table ?

Comment: Yep, that's what I was recommending.  I think it would be hard for someone to help you without seeing what data the markeup is binding to.